# What nomenclature do you use for UI Elements

Tags: design-patterns, documentation

Having worked with multiple OSs, platforms and UI Kits I always run into the problem of how to consistently naming things be that larger structures with names like Widgets, Views, Forms, Controls or smaller structures like Checkbox, Combobox, Disclosure Arrow, ...

This being a community wiki, the question is how do you name the ui elements that you use, how do you make sure you stick to a schema that everybody knows (that also means your users when you describe things in your documentation). What resources do you use as reference.

Answer (score 6):

Check this out: http://sixrevisions.com/user-interface/creating-a-user-interface-that-speaks-your-users-language/

Comment: The above example is great! Any more such examples? @g.dot